# Terminating half of a pipe on Linux does not terminate the other half

Tags: linux, shell, unix, pipe

I have a `filewatch` program:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 # On Linux, uses inotifywait -mre close_write, and on OS X uses fswatch.

 set -e

 [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]] && echo "args count" && exit 2
 if [[ `uname` = "Linux" ]]; then
     inotifywait -mcre close_write "$1" | sed 's/,".*",//'     
 elif [[ `uname` = "Darwin" ]]; then
     # sed on OSX/BSD wants -l for line-buffering
     fswatch "$1" | sed -l 's/^[a-f0-9]\{1,\} //'
 fi
 echo "fswatch: $$ exiting"
```

And a construct i'm trying to use from a script (and I am testing with it on the command line on CentOS now):

`filewatch . | while read line; do echo "file $line has changed\!\!"; done &`

So what I am hoping this does is it will let me process, one line at a time, the output of `inotify`, which of course sends out one line for each file it has detected a change on.

Now for my script to clean stuff up properly I need to be able to kill this whole backgrounded pipeline when the script exits.

So i run it and then if I run `kill` on either the first part of the pipe or the second part, the other part does not terminate.

So I think if I kill the `while read line` part (which should be `sh` (`zsh` in the case of running on the cmd line)) then `filewatch` should be receiving a SIGPIPE. Okay so I am not handling that, I guess it can keep running.

If I kill `filewatch`, though, it looks like `zsh` continues with its `while read line`. Why?

Comment: I may have to account for this inconsistency between environments by just using `inotify` without `-m` and re-spawning it each time. Eliminates the need to kill it, i can just stop spawning it once i'm done. This is not really that good, though, because it has to re-establish all the watches each time and misses a bunch of stuff when things change quickly

Comment: I am pretty sure your problem goes away if you don't pipe though `sed` in your filewatch script.

Comment: How else can I construct a script that normalizes the output?

Comment: [inotifywait(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) mentions a `--format` option.

Comment: Oh good point. I'll look into that.